# Sitefinity, intercepting page events

Tags: sitefinity

Sitefinity has some documentation on how to create a page programmatically, but what I really want to do is to perform some additional logic when the "Create Page" event is fired.

From a high-level, how would one go about doing this? Is there certain interface to implement, or a class to extend?

I'm using SiteFinity 4 (4.4)

Answer (score 0):

If you download SDK, you will find Utilities class which contains sample code for creating pages, templates etc.

You can create pages by using PageManager or a fluent API - everything is in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I'm not looking to create a page. I just want to attach an event handler that will get called when a page is created. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work on the Sitefinity team at Telerik.*

I'm talking from memory here, but usually you can subscribe to the Executed event of each manager in Sitefinity. It is fired on each action you perform from that manager and passes you arguments about the current command being executed. You'll have to debug and inspect what is the name of the command when creating pages, and if so do what you need.

Another alternative is to implement custom workflow and include your coded step somewhere. More info here: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/workflow-for-content-modules/custom-workflow

If you open a support ticket or write in the forums with more details, we would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post "[Automatically create other language versions of the page using Sitefinity API](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/automatically-create-other-language-versions-of-the-page-using-sitefinity-api.aspx)" will help...